# Vue 3 vendor bundle is bloated with @babel/parser/lib when vue.esm-bundler.js is used in webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I created a Vue 3 project and using webpack for bundling the package. Since I have in-DOM templates, I cannot go with the default @runtime-dom. So I have aliased Vue to point to vue.esm-bundler.js.

The issue I am facing is that, when I take a prod build, my vendor bundle is bloated with @babel/parser/lib.

Sample project to reproduce this issue is available [here](https://github.com/sajuthankathurai/webpack-vue3/)

Steps to follow:

1. npm install
2. npm run bundle

Open dist folder and see the Webpack bundle analyser report.

[image]

For ease of config, pasting the configs below.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const devMode = options.mode != "production";
  return {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: {
      "vue-bundle": "./entry/main.js",
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  "@babel/preset-env",
                  {
                    targets: [">25%"],
                    debug: true,
                    corejs: "3.6.5",
                    useBuiltIns: false,
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: "vue-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({        
        openAnalyzer: false,
        analyzerMode: "static",
        reportFilename: "webpack_bundle_analyser_report.html",
        defaultSizes: "gzip",
      }),
    ],
    optimization: {
      mangleWasmImports: true,
      removeAvailableModules: true,
      sideEffects: true,
      minimize: devMode ? false : true,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
          exclude: /\/node-modules/,
          parallel: 4,
          extractComments: false,
        }),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: "vendor-bundle",
            chunks: "all",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    devtool: devMode ? "eval-cheap-source-map" : false,
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
      alias: {
        vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
      },
    },
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testPro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.js",
    "bundle-dev": "webpack --mode=development --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-beta.4",
    "webpack": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Entry file main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from '../App.vue';

createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

Not able to get what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe it is a bug in Vue 3 so I submitted a bug report - you can track it [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2515)

...I reproduced it myself using Vue CLI just to eliminate the chance the problem is in your Webpack config

You have 2 options to workaround this issue:

1. If you don't need to release right now, just work on your project and wait for a fix (I'm pretty sure it will be fixed - Vue builds for a browser which include compiler does not depend on `@babel/parser` so it's clear Vue don't need it to work correctly inside browser)
2. Don't use in-DOM templates and `template` option (string templates) - put everything in `.vue` files, `<template></template>` blocks - [Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#runtime-compiler-vs-runtime-only). Then you don't need a build with compiler...

EDIT: removed the part about missing `process.env.NODE_ENV` as `--mode` param to Webpack CLI does exactly that...

Comment: Thanks @Michal. Is there any workaround for this issue to get rid of @babel/parser/lib ?